# What is being installed when / disk usage is > 85 %

Tags: package, centos

We're running a few Centos 7 VMs, GCP, and for the past week we get disk space alerts on / disk/partition. The following is the image layout and additional attached disk and mounted shared file system

```
Filesystem                     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                        63G     0   63G   0% /dev
tmpfs                           63G     0   63G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                           63G  321M   63G   1% /run
tmpfs                           63G     0   63G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                       50G   43G  7.7G  85% /
/dev/sda1                      200M   12M  189M   6% /boot/efi
/dev/mapper/data_vg1-data_lv1   99G   41G   53G  44% /app
10.10.10.10:/fileshare         207G   85G  113G  43% /mnt/fileshare
tmpfs                           13G     0   13G   0% /run/user/1006
tmpfs                           13G     0   13G   0% /run/user/1031
```

each evening around 1AM UTC we get an alert that "/" disk/partition is disk usage > 85%. After about 1/2 hr disk size < 30%. I checked when yum ran last to install a package but that was the day before. I somehow assume that some packages get installed by GCP but not sure. I tried RPM package manager to get some answers but to no avail. What are some of the ways, tools, commands to use to find what this disk usage spike causes. Any thougths?

Comment: Since var doesn't seem to be on a separate file system, I would look at log files as a first port of call.

Comment: Thank you @RamanSailopal for thee info. I did find the offending file. It was a file create by an automation process and the file was only on the file system for about 1 hour and then got deleted. Sorry for the late update